# Преобразование текста в картинку PHP

Tags: php

я пытаюсь преобразовать текст в картинку с помощью PHP, есть полностью работоспособный код, который без проблем преобразует текст в картинку, но почему-то вместо русского текста выдаются кракозябры, с английским текстом проблем нет. Что делать? помогите пожалуйста.

```
<?php
$input_text = 'фыв';
$width = (strlen($input_text) * 9) + 20;
$height = 30;

$textImage = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$color = imagecolorallocate($textImage, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($textImage, $color);
imagestring($textImage, 5, 10, 5, $input_text, 0xFFFFFF);


// create background image layer
$background = imagecreatefromjpeg('bg.jpeg');

// Merge background image and text image layers
imagecopymerge($background, $textImage, 15, 15, 0, 0, $width, $height, 100);


$output = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($output, $background, 0, 0, 20, 13, $width, $height);


ob_start();
imagepng($output);
printf('<img id="output" src="data:image/png;base64,%s" />', base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
?>
```

Comment: В описании imagestring http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php сказано, что можно выбрать один из стандартных latin2 шрифтов, либо использовать свой, загруженный ранее, через imageloadfont. Так вот в кодировке latin2 никаких русских символов нет. Значит вам требуется где то взять и загрузить фонт содержащий русские символы, причем для той кодировки, в которой вы передаете ему строку с текстом

Comment: Можете добавить в ответ пример? я выберу его правильным ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте в начале

```
header("Content-type: image/png; charset=utf-8");
```